# Origin of the terminology "Einstein frame" and "Jordan frame"

Tags: theoretical-physics, relativity-theory

Consider a classical scalar-tensor theory (I'm following [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0403063v3))

\begin{equation}
   S=\int d^4x\sqrt{-g}\left(
       \frac{1}{2\kappa^2}\mathcal{A}\left(\Phi\right)R
       -\frac{1}{2}\mathcal{B}\left(\Phi\right)\left(\nabla\Phi\right)^2
       - V\left(\Phi\right) 
   \right)
   +
   S_m\left[e^{2\alpha\left(\Phi\right)}g_{\mu\nu},\psi_m\right]
\end{equation}

The Ricci scalar is $R$, the scalar field is $\Phi$, and $\psi_m$ are the ''matter fields''. The theory is said to be in the ''Einstein frame'' if $\mathcal{A}=1,\mathcal{B}=1$, and is said to be in the ''Jordan frame'' if $\alpha=0,\mathcal{B}=1$.

My question is: what is the origin of this terminology? It looks like the term ''Einstein frame'' was introduced by [Hawking](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-25/issue-2/Black-holes-in-the-Brans-Dicke-theory-of-gravitation/cmp/1103857885.full), but I can't figure out where the first paper where ''Jordan frame'' was coined (in Hawking's paper he calls it the ''Brans-Dicke frame'').